# Apalike with year unavailable

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

How can I cite a `@misc` reference where publication year is not available using the `apalike` bibliography style without getting an output like `(somekey, )` (note the missing year after the comma) and warnings like the ones below?

```
Warning--empty year in somekey
```

Since the `@misc` reference is just an online resource where the year is not available, then I am having this issue because this particular style is based on the (author/key, year) combination. But is there a way to tell to just *omit* the year for this kind of `@misc`
 items? (e.g. just `(somekey)` without any comma)

Comment: Not really, `apalike` generally wants and needs a year (unless you can accept weird output like "(somekey, )"). You could try `year = {n.d.},` Or you could look into using a style that deals with missing years more gracefully (I don't know a style like that off the top of my head).

Comment: Many thanks @moewe, apparently there are no standard Bibtex styles which support missing years more gracefully, probably I should find a non-standard one...

Comment: You could try `natbib`'s `plainnat` (or any other `natbib` standard style). You'll still get a warning, but the output will be OK-ish.

Comment: Authoryear-type citation call-outs tend to become unhelpful if there's no `year` component. As @moewe has already noted, setting `year="n.d."` and thus creating citation call-outs of the type `(Smith, n.d.)` are probably preferable to `(Smith, )`.