# Canonical handling of references without year in natbib and apalike

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apa-style

For a larger project with many authors I want to know how to handle references without year (typically "unpublished" or "forthcoming") while the main bibliography setup is natbib and apalike.

The built-in behaviour of natbib with apalike is to issue an error message that a reference without year cannot be handled and than swiches the bibliographystyle for all references. Is there a solution for this problem at all and how does it look? A canonical solution that can be transferred to other situations as well is much preferred.

I tried putting

```
year = {no year},
```

in the `.bib` file entry, but this does not really work, it produced "Author (year)" in the text, dropping the word "no" here.

```
year = {none},
```

works in the sense that the citation in text and the bibliography coinceede and that it does not throw error messages. Can this solution by considered canonical?

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546526/apalike-with-year-unavailable you can use `year = {n.d.}`.

Comment: But see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/citations-with-no-date-e-g-aristotle-n-d to make it work properly.